# A Question About RegExp in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a regular expression 
^([+/-]?([0-9]+(.)?)|([0-9]*.[0-9]+))$ 
I create it by two ways

```
var _regex = "^([+/-]?([0-9]+(\.)?)|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+))$";
var _regexFloat = new RegExp(_regex);
```

and

```
var _regexFloat = /^([+/-]?([0-9]+(\.)?)|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+))$/ ;
```

the testing data is "1a" and "a1". 
at the second way, it work fine. 
but in the first way, it returns true.

Can anyone suggest me if I have something wrong.

Thanks very much.

Environment:

> Windows Server 2003 
>  IE 6

Comment: Hello, what is this regex for ? Is it to know if a string contains a float ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you'll need to escape those backslashes in the string (in the first version).

Try this:

```
var _regex = "^([+/-]?([0-9]+(\\.)?)|([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+))$";
var _regexFloat = new RegExp(_regex);
```

Comment: Of course this is exactly why the second syntax exists.  Escaping makes it less readable.

Comment: I agree, I use the second version.